# Java library to check a video's metadata (if it's 1080p, 720p, etc)

Tags: java, video, metadata

I'm currently looking for a library that looks at a videos metadata and see if the video is 1080p, 720p or a least be able get the basic metadata(resolution, bitrate, etc) so I could do the calculations to check myself.

I'm hoping the library is light in size, cross platform and it can support a number of the main formats. Something like https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor but of course for videos.

I tried searching around and found nothing, does such a library exist?

Comment: Haha ok, you know what I mean, I've added the question :P

Comment: +1 this question is interesting.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: He's looking for a java library to detect video formats. Is that not clear? If not, edit. Sarcastic comments are not productive.

Comment: I know this is an old question, and was closed, but support for video files has recently landed in [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor).

Comment: Nice. Glad they finally added video support. It was a great library when I used it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tried it yet, but seems [Java MP4 Parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser) library is what I've been looking for. It is able to read and edit metadata, cross platform and seems to be light in file size.

An excerpt from the github documentation:

> ### Java MP4 Parser
>
> A Java API to read, write and create MP4 container. Manipulating
>   containers is different from encoding and decoding videos and audio.
>   Using the library
>
> The library is published to Maven repositories. Each release is pushed
>   to a staging repository which is published on the release page. On
>   request specific releases can be pushed to maven central.
>
> ```
>   <dependency>
>     <groupId>com.googlecode.mp4parser</groupId>
>     <artifactId>isoparser</artifactId>
>     <version>1.1.7</version>
>   </dependency>
> ```
>
> For projects that do not use a dependency management tool each
>   release's artifacts (jar, javadoc-jar, source-jar) are attached to the
>   release page. Please be aware that the project requires the
>   aspectj-rt.jar library.
>
> ### What can you do?
>
> Typical tasks for the MP4 Parser are:
>
> - Muxing audio/video into an MP4 file
> - Append recordings that use same encode settings
> - Adding/Changing metadata
> - Shorten recordings by omitting frames My examples will all use H264 and AAC as these two codecs are most typical for MP4 files. AC-3 is
>     also not uncommon as the codec is well known from DVD. There are also
>     MP4 files with H263/MPEG-2 video tracks but they are no longer used
>     widespread as most android phones. You can also
>
> ### Muxing Audio/Video
>
> The API and the process is straight-forward:
>
> You wrap each raw format file into an appropriate Track object.
>
> > H264TrackImpl h264Track = new H264TrackImpl(new
> >     FileDataSourceImpl("video.h264")); AACTrackImpl aacTrack = new
> >     AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl("audio.aac"));
>
> These Track object are then added to a Movie object
>
> ```
> Movie movie = new Movie();
> movie.addTrack(h264Track);
> movie.addTrack(aacTrack);
> ```
>
> The Movie object is fed into an MP4Builder to create the container.
>
> ```
> Container mp4file = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);
> ```
>
> Write the container to an appropriate sink.
>
> FileChannel fc = new FileOutputStream(new
>   File("output.mp4")).getChannel(); mp4file.writeContainer(fc);
>   fc.close(); There are cases where the frame rate is signalled out of
>   band or is known in advance so that the H264 doesn't contain it
>   literally. In this case you will have to supply it to the constructor.
>
> There are Track implementations for the following formats:
>
> - H264
> - AAC
> - AC3
> - EC3
>
> and additionally two subtitle tracks that do not directly wrap a raw
>   format but they are conceptually similar.
>
> ### Typical Issues
>
> Audio and video are not in sync. Whenever there are problems with
>   timing possible make sure to start
>
> ### Audio starts before video
>
> In AAC there are always samplerate/1024 sample/s so each sample's
>   duration is 1000 * 1024 / samplerate milliseconds.
>
> - 48KHz => ~21.3ms
> - 44.1KHz => ~23.2ms
>
> By omitting samples from the start you can easily shorten the audio
>   track. Remove as many as you need. You will not be able to match audio
>   and video exactly with that but the human perception is more sensible
>   to early audio than to late audio.
>
> Remember: If someone is only 10 meters away the delay between audio
>   and video is >30ms. The brain is used to that!
>
> AACTrackImpl aacTrackOriginal = new AACTrackImpl(new
>   FileDataSourceImpl("audio.aac")); // removes the first sample and
>   shortens the AAC track by ~22ms CroppedTrack aacTrackShort = new
>   CroppedTrack(aacTrackOriginal, 1, aacTrack.getSamples().size());
>
> ### Append Recordings with Same Encode Settings
>
> It is important to emphasize that you cannot append any two tracks
>   with:
>
> - Different resolutions
> - Different frame-rates
>
> ### What can't you do?
>
> Create JPEGs from a movie. No - this is no decoder. The MP4 Parser
>   doesn't know how to do that. Create a movie from JPEGs

Comment: Please improve this answer, even if it is a self-answer.

Comment: What would you suggest? The library is exactly what I was looking for 4 years ago.

Comment: following the guidance of these below comments ....

Comment: Just linking to your own library (or utility) or someone else's is not a good answer. In fact it is considered Not An Answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code using it to do so and disclaiming makes for a good answer. See: [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/)

Comment: See also [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)

Comment: Did a couple of more edits. If you think it can be improved more, feel free to edit it. The other answer could probably can be improved too.

Comment: does it support getting thumbnail from video ?

Comment: No, it doesn't support that. It's not a decoder.

Answer (score 3):

Try these api's :

- [Java Media Frame Work](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) [[Tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2001/jw-0504-jmf2.html)]
- [jffmpeg](http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/)
- [jvlc](http://trac.videolan.org/jvlc)
- [vlcj](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj)
- [gstreamer-java](http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/)
- [Fobs4JMF](http://fobs.sourceforge.net/index.html)
- [Video4Linux4Java](http://code.google.com/p/v4l4j/)

Comment: Thanks for the links, all seem very heavy and mostly native libraries. Maybe the JMFW would be the closest but can it get the metadata I need? A quick search couldn't find how it can get metadata.

Comment: @Zammbi:Check the tutorial for jmf,i have added.

Comment: JMF is kind of old technology and hasn't really aged very well. It's unlikely that you'll be able to handle the more modern containers/codecs out there with it.