# Get Meta content from video

Tags: java, video

I keed to know complete meta data of an uploaded video using java , life frame rate , number of frames , quality of video , length and parse the star cast from the first few frames , what is the way of doing this.

Comment: You're probably best to use a 3rd party app and read the results in, e.g. libmpeg.

Comment: This post may have [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142645/java-library-to-check-a-videos-metadata-if-its-1080p-720p-etc) you're looking for.